# Extract an array from object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, foreach

I'm having an issue trying to extract an `array` from an `object`. The structure is as follows:

```
[]
  0: Array(4)
     0: 0
     1: 5
     2: 500
     3: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I've tried `object.keys`, `for` and `foreach` loops but I haven't been able to find a solution. This example is what I get when I use `console.log(object)`. When I put `console.log(object.length)` I get `0` as an output. But the type is an `object`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is an array, containing a single element, which is also an array, of 4 elements. Tell us **what** you want to extract, and show what you tried.

Comment: Can you give the structure from `JSON.stringify`ing it instead please, as well as an example of what structure you want to extract?

Comment: Json.stringify gives me {"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":true,"value":. JBNizet when i use console.log(typeof this.test_array) it indicates that it is an object.

Comment: what is the type of that object? Add the sections of code where you: declare the object and invoke the console.log

Comment: Sounds like it may be an observable, can you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Yes it is an observable, I added the http request code.

Comment: Okay. So, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I need to extract the array embeded in the object.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the observable then

Answer (score 0):

Using HttpClient

```
getTests(): Observable<Test[]> {
   //Your function return a Observable, forget equal to this.test.array or whatever
   return this.http
       .get<Idea[]>(this.url) //<--get, return your json
       .map(data => data[3]); //<--we change the response, instead of returning
                              //   all the object we only return the element[3]

//And you use 
getTest().subscribe((data:Idea[])=>{
   console.log(data);
   //If you have a public variable "test_array" you can do
   this.test_array=data;
   })
```

Comment: I get an error that says Type 'Observable<Test>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Idea[]>'.

Comment: change "Idea" and "Test" for "any". I don't know as your interfaces are

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work: it gives ` Argument of type '(data: Idea[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Idea) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Idea' is not assignable to type 'Idea[]'. `

Answer (score 0):

I see three levels of array, your returned object is an array, the index [0] is also an array, then you have an array of 5 at index 3

Try this:

```
getTests(): Observable<any[]> {
   return this.http
       .get<any[]>(this.url) 
       .map(data => data[0][3]); 

getTest().subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data);
   //If you have a public variable "test_array" you can do
   this.test_array=data;
   })
```